# Open source screen recorder for windows that can pause and has area selection

Tags: windows, open-source, screen-recording

**Is there any Open source screen recorder for windows that can**

**1.pause the recording**

**2.Has the option to record a selected area?**

"ShareX" is opensource and has area selection option. But it cannot pause the recording.

So, is there any alternative to "Sharex" ?

**Apart from OBS?**

Because OBS does not run smoothly on my device. It gets lagged and one time I lost my recording-It got stuck on "stopping recording..."

Edit: Thanks for all the answers. But OBS works for me now.

Comment: Windows comes with screen capture and recording software; how is this inadequate for your needs?

Comment: @JeffZeitlin  Did you mean gamebar? but it can only capture games...

Comment: It can and does capture any window you want it to.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin But it can't select area, can it?

Comment: Win-Shift-S for taking a static screen shot.

Comment: Using the Game Bar for video recording I found documented at https://helpdeskgeek.com/windows-10/how-to-record-your-screen-on-windows-10/

Comment: @JeffZeitlin No no, I meant can it record only a selected part of the screen

Comment: Like many screen recording software does

Comment: From my experience, OBS Studio works well for this. What device are you running it on?

Answer (score 2):

ShareX can pause recordings, you just need to configure a hotkey.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Minitool Video Converter is a great software for screen recording on windows. It has Video Converter in its name. But it also has a function to record the screen. It can pause the recording and has the option to record a selected area too. It also supports mouse highlighting.

Link to download it -
https://cdn2.minitool.com/?p=vc&e=vc-free

Some screenshots -

[image: Minitool Video Converter Screenshot]

[image: Minitool Screen Recorder Screenshot]

Comment: Wow thanks! why didnt all the sites I read didnt even mention this? This is a very good tool!Thanks again to pointing this out. ps: can't upvote because I don't yet have enough points to do that

Comment: But the [website](https://videoconvert.minitool.com/) of Minitool says that it has copyright? Is it not opensource? But it seems to have no restrictions like time limit or watermark? I dont know why it has every features if it is not opensource. Seems like it is only free temporarily.

Comment: Note: I am not accepting this answer for now, because I am hoping that someone will point out an opensource software.

Comment: It doesn't have any restrictions, time limit or watermark, I personally use it and that's why I recommended it.

Comment: It is an opensource software, it is fully free to use

Comment: Thanks, but an  [Opensource software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-source_software) is a software whose source code is available to the public. So it will always be free because If the developer decides to make it a paid software, people will just download the previous free version of it which can be posted by anyone because its opensource. // contrary to this , the app "minitool video converter" is free but not opensource. So they can change the software to make it a paid software anytime with a forced update.

Comment: @Abhinav P B Not every freeware have to be open sorce.

Comment: @convert Yeah, But I wanted an opensource software. not just a free one.

Answer (score 1):

As for open source solutions, here a list:

[Freeseer](https://freeseer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/about/)

[OBS Studio](https://obsproject.com/)

[Captura](https://mathewsachin.github.io/Captura/) (is dead at the moment or to be more precise not maintained, but this can change in the future)

[CamStudio](https://camstudio.org/)

[UltraVnc screen recorder](https://uvnc.com/screenrecorder/)

Answer (score 1):

Vokoscreen would be your best bet: https://linuxecke.volkoh.de/vokoscreen/vokoscreen.html

- Open source.
- Works on Windows and Linux.
- Can pause

[image]

Comment: Also, as of ShareX 15.0, you can pause a recording.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations – and thanks for sharing your insights! But could you please **[edit]** your answer to include how the recommended software meets the requirements, and what makes it especially recommendable? Please see [our discussion on answer quality](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/356/185) for details and background. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I installed it but when I launch it , I get an error message "Wayland desktop session detected.   Please install the package
gstreamer-plugin-pipewire"

Comment: @Sophie: Try the latest version which came out earlier this month. If it still persists, create a GitHub issue or email the dev to signal the problem.